# How to change UIPageViewController direction of paging curl animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, globalization, uipageviewcontroller

I need to display Arabic (Right To Left) content and couldn't find any method to rotate animation of the page curl found by UIPageViewController because basically Arabic books should be turned from Left to right.

Comment: If you change the iOS language to Arabic and use one of the built-in iOS apps that uses page curl (the only one I can think of is Maps), do you see the page curl flipped? I'm asking as I wonder if the support is there at all (which would be a globalization bug in iOS)

Comment: No, there's no support at all for any animation aspect regarding RTL languages... Neither for page curl, nor Push and Pop UIViewControllers! I was looking for a hack around.

Comment: You know what! Even after changing my iOS language into Arabic and downloading an Arabic book from iBooks, animation didn't change! I had to swipe from right to left to go to next page!!

Comment: @ShadyA.Elyaski if you turn the mainWindow co-ordinates upside down, and all the elements in in the page also rotated upside down, would it give you that effect?

Comment: @calvinBhai I managed to rotate the UIPageViewController view 180 degrees and then rotating all subviews to another 180 (to fix the upside down issue). The problem now is the gesture recognizers need to be mirrored! animation works perfectly. but how can I intercept all touches going to that that specific controller and mirror each touch before it's actually handled ??

Comment: what specific issues do you have with the touches and gesture recognizers?

Comment: See the post http://stackoverflow.com/a/11124807/400909

Answer (score 2):

If you are supporting only portrait mode then you should look at the `UIPageViewController delegate` method `pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:` and return `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax`.

But if you want to support both landscape and portrait then you could keep the default spine location animations but provide the pages in the opposite direction than requested like this

In the `: pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` return the next page
and in the `: pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController` just return the previous one.