# IOS 5 Page Curl, Change direction of Curl

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

Please tell me how to change the default direction(right to left) to left to right?

[image: Change the direction to left to right]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625375/iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions

Comment: I'm using default page based application provided in ios 5

Comment: It's not a duplicate, the link you referred does not use uipageviewcontroller of ios5

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705332/how-to-change-uipageviewcontroller-direction-of-paging-curl-animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the default for most configurations is
>   UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin which places the spine on the
>   left hand side or top of the screen depending on whether the
>   navigation orientation is horizontal or vertical. Similarly, **the
>   UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax setting will position the spine
>   at the right or bottom edge of the display**.

hope this helps.

**Reference:** http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_a_Page_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_UIPageViewController

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the method you need:

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

This is a pageViewController Method: check the reference out [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) I think setting the direction should do it.