# RTL languages uipageviewcontroller curl animation for one view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I need to perform the transitions of the uipageviewcontroller from right to left. So I look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003319/rtl-languages-uipageviewcontroller-animation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705332/how-to-change-uipageviewcontroller-direction-of-paging-curl-animation) examples. But difference is I have one viewcontroller to show at a time and `pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:` can only return `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin` not `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax`. This is what I have done so far.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

NSUInteger index = [(APPChildViewController *)viewController index];

if (index == 0) {
    return nil;
}

// Decrease the index by 1 to return
index--;

return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

NSUInteger index = [(APPChildViewController *)viewController index];

index++;

if (index == 15) {
    return nil;
}

return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];}

- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
               spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
UIViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentViewController];
[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

self.pageController.doubleSided = NO;
//Return the spine location
return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;
}
```

How can I get the curl working properly with the `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin`?. Also I cannot use Page-Based Application template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003319/rtl-languages-uipageviewcontroller-animation?lq=1) I found the solution. This is the code.

```
- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
UIViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentViewController];
[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

self.pageController.doubleSided = NO;
return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax;
}
```